# Criar um link com dados e passar por post

Tags: jquery, link

Não sei se é possível, mas gostaria de criar um link (ou simular um) onde preciso passar dados para a página desse link, mas não gostaria de passar esses dados por `get` e sim por `post`, para não ficar exibindo os dados (eu sei que para um usuário avançado será possível ver esses dados, mas não haveria problema).

Abaixo o link que estou criando:

```
<a href="pagina_a_ser_chamada" data-usuario="1" data-cliente="3" class="openLink">
    Abrir dados do cliente 3
</a>

<a href="pagina_a_ser_chamada" data-usuario="1" data-cliente="4" class="openLink">
    Abrir dados do cliente 4
</a>

<a href="pagina_a_ser_chamada" data-usuario="1" data-cliente="5" class="openLink">
    Abrir dados do cliente 5
</a>
```

Tentei fazer algo com jQuery, mas não consegui passar os dados `usuario` e `cliente` e **não** quero ter de passar assim `pagina_a_ser_chamada?usuario=1&cliente=3`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.openLink').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        window.open($(this).attr('href'), '_blank');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Essa pergunta é bem interessante, recomendo fazer a solução utilizando um formulário, que pode ser escondido do usuário.

Não me vem a cabeça uma forma de abrir uma nova aba utilizando um POST sem a utilização de um formulário.

Edit: O uso do attributo `target="_blank"` faz possível abrir a página em uma nova janela/aba, porém entendi equivocadamente que era mandatório, mas não é.

Form para utilização:

```
<form action="#" method="post" style="display:none" id="transport">
    <input type="hidden" name="usuario" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cliente" />
</form>
```

No form coloquei dois inputs baseado nos atributos customizados do link, mas se quiser poderá criar os inputs conforme a necessidade, seja no HTML ou via JavaScript.

Link a ser clicado:

```
<a href="pagina_a_ser_chamada" data-usuario="1" data-cliente="3" class="openLink">
    Clique aqui
</a>
```

Javascript:

```
function extractData(link) {
    var obj = {},
        attributes = link.attributes,
        count = attributes.length;

    for(var i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        var prefixLocation = attributes[i].name.search('data-');

        if(prefixLocation != -1) {
            obj[attributes[i].name.substr(prefixLocation + 5)] = attributes[i].value;
        }
    }

    return obj;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.openLink').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $form = $('#transport');

        // Extrai os dados dos atributos customizados do link tirando o prefixo "data-"
        var data = extractData(this); 

        // Preenche os dados no form
        for(var attr in data) {
            $form.find('input[name="' + attr + '"]').val(data[attr]);
        }

        // Atualiza o action do form com o href do link
        $form.attr('action', this.href);

        // Submete o form
        $form.submit();
    });
});
```

O exemplo pode ser visto nesse [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4FhxD/), porém ele não funciona nesse ambiente por causa das regras de segurança e cross-domain, é apenas um local para ver o preenchimento do formulário no HTML.

Para ver o resultado recomendo testar num ambiente mais real.

Comment: Entendi o que me passou e o meu grande problema, algo que esqueci de postar é que é um link para cada cliente, sendo assim, a solução que passou não atende... sim, pode ter sido uma falha minha aqui tbm... mas vou pensar como resolver meu problema com a solução que enviou... Obrigado

Comment: A criação do `form` pode ser feita no script, tente incluir mais dados de como deve ser gerado que eu atualizo a resposta.

Comment: Fiz uma edição na pergunta, mostrando que é um link para cada cliente, é só isso mesmo que muda.. Valew

Comment: Atualizei o JavaScript com a atribuição do `href` do link ao `action` do formulário, que eu tinha esquecido. Assim, com apenas um form você pode usá-lo para quantos links quiser e acredito que a quantidade de parâmetros do link seja fixa, caso seja variável é preciso modificar o script para considerar isso.

Answer (score 1):

Somente é possível enviar `POST` através de forms, server-side ou gambiarra xD

```
<form action="pagina_a_ser_chamada" method="post">
    <input type="hidden"  name="usuario" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden"  name="cliente" value="3" />
    <input type="submit" class="openLink" value="Clique aqui" />
</form>
```

Se estiver usando PHP experimente [variáveis de sessão](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.session.php)

```
$_SESSION['usuario'] = 1;
$_SESSION['cliente'] = 3;
```

Estas variáveis poderão ser vistas em qualquer parte do seu código, e o usuário do seu site não irá velas...

=)

Pode usar segmentos da url

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'] = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$segments = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH']);
```

A variável `$segments` contem por exemplo localhost/site/pagina

```
array 
  0 => string 'localhost' 
  1 => string 'site' 
  2 => string 'pagina'
```

com esse metódo os links ficariam o seguinte

```
<a href="pagina_a_ser_chamada/1/4" class="openLink">
    Abrir dados do cliente 4
</a>
```

Comment: Gambiarras é o que mais estou fazendo... infelizmente..  . sei que não postei, mas o meu problema de criar o form é que são vários links, um para cada cliente, dai assim não irá dar certo.

Comment: @MarceloDiniz Voce pode usar JQuery para quando clicar no link ele execute um [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) que irá definir a SESSÃO para este usuário

Comment: Não entendi o que quiz dizer, eu já utilizo muito ajax no sistema que estou fazendo, mas nessa parte não pretendo usar por causa de alguns pontos do sistema, e por isso que irei "recarregar para a nova página"